# linux terminal text manipulation

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I am now studying linux command line and this question is in my head for almost a week but i think still i have not found optimal solution,  question is next: i have file with is formatted in a bad way one word on each line:

```
SUSE

FEDORA

SUSE

UBUNTU

FEDORA


10.2 

10 

11.0 

8.04 

8 
10.3 

6.10 

2006-12-07 

2008-11-25 

2008-06-19 

2008-04-24 

2007-11-08 

2007-10-04 

2006-10-26 

2007-05-31 

2007-10-18
```

as you see those are linux distros with version and release dates right formatting is next :

```
2008-11-25  SUSE    10.2

2008-06-19  FEDORA  10

2008-04-24  SUSE    11.0
...
```

I believe there must be very simple way to sort this right, i mean with one line of commands, not to save in other file and then paste in other file.

Comment: Who does `2006-12-07` belong to if `SUSE`  is `2008-11-25 `? You can use `wc -l`, `split` & `paste`, but the number of line have to make sense.

Comment: your keyword, date, and version counts don't match.  If you post a realistic sample, perhaps more people can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a matching number of items from you post

```
SUSE
FEDORA
SUSE
UBUNTU
FEDORA
10.2
10
11.0
8.04
8 10.3
2006-12-07
2008-11-25
2008-06-19
2008-04-24
2007-11-08
```

This script will convert to 3 columns and reorder fields

```
pr -3t filename | awk '{print $3,$1,$2}'

2006-12-07 SUSE 10.2
2008-11-25 FEDORA 10
2008-06-19 SUSE 11.0
2008-04-24 UBUNTU 8.04
10.3 FEDORA 8
```

Comment: thanks! this is the exact solution which i thought , there would be.

Answer (score 0):

You could run `vi filename` and then execute :g/^$/d for the newlines.

Then for positioning you can use Ctrl-c and y to copy. You may need to add spaces to the last line for the versions so you can copy it all in visual-block mode. Then you can paste in a block using Shift-p.

Comment: thanks!  but i think the answer without vim is better.